# Displaying videos in ionic 3 issue

Tags: html, ionic-framework, ionic3, mobile-development

**How can I display videos in ionic 3 , i have used ionic video player plugin but it does not contain video controls , also i have used video html5 tag but it did not work , please help me to solve this issue ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the video tag use native streaming media cordova plugin.
visit below link for more information 
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/streaming-media.
This Plugin works with audio and video player and supports both android and ios.

Another plugin is also there but it supports Android only. For more Information visit https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/video-player/

Answer (score 1):

i have the same issue but i solved it using the below code..

```
<div align="center" class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
  <video width="400" autoplay loop class="embed-responsive-item" controls>
    <source src="path/to/the/file.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
</div>
```

hope this will helps you..